How to correctly enter an array of objects in terminal using nconf?
I'm newbie in nonf and encountered the following problem: I need to get an array of objects as shown below:
"myArray":[
   {
      "Name":"Jhon",
      "Age":30,
      "Animal":"cat"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Anna",
      "Age":25,
      "Animal":"null"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Lex",
      "Age":50,
      "Animal":"rabbit"
   }
]



My js code:
const path = require('path');
////////////////////////////

nconf.set('myArray', nconf.get('myArray'));
nconf.save();


When I set the parameters in the terminal:
node example.js --myArray.Name=Daniel --myArray.Age=18 --myArray.Animal=parrot --myArray.Name=Anna --myArray.Age=25 --myArray.Animal=null --myArray.Name=Lex --myArray.Age=50 --myArray.Animal=rabbit

I get the following picture:
"myArray":[
   "Name":[
      "Daniel",
      "Anna",
      "Lex"
    ],
    "Age":[
       "18",
       "25",
       "50"
    ],
    "Animal":[
       "parrot",
       "null",
       "rabbit"
    ]
]

How can I get an array of objects like in the first one?
